# How to find the next or previous or next row

Tags: mysql

I have a table with customer details

```
id,title,first_name,surname
```

When I use

```
SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY surname,first_name,title;
```

How can I get the previous or next row based on the id without reading the entire table.

Comment: If you execute this query, you already got the entire table.

Comment: do you mean you only want one row returned?

Comment: Are you trying to find the next id in the sequence that will be inserted with a new entry.  If so maybe select max(id)+1 from customers may be what you want?

Answer (score 2):

next:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id > XYZ ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

previous:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id < XYZ ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

where XYZ is your number

Comment: this will NOT be in the order specified by the ORDER BY clause

Comment: Yes this doesn't work as the id's are not in ascending order. At the moment I'm reading all the rows then adding or subtracting to find the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

If the ID type is integer and `nextID = currentID + 1`. so you can write your query as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers 
WHERE id = (currentID + 1) 
ORDER BY surname,first_name,title;
```

Comment: this will NOT be in the order specified by the ORDER BY clause